# Adding filter to button in Flash Builder AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, filter, flash-builder, addition

I try to add a dropshadow effect to some buttons at creationComplete event.

import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;

```
// #1 Does work but removes other filters
protected function onButtonCreate(e:Event):void
{
 (e.target as Button).filters = [new DropShadowFilter(1,45,0x000000,0.4,4,4,2,1,false,true,false)];
}


// #2 Does not work
protected function onButtonCreate(e:Event):void
{
 (e.target as Button).filters.push(new DropShadowFilter(1,45,0x000000,0.4,4,4,2,1,false,true,false));
}


// #3 Does not work
protected function onButtonCreate(e:Event):void
{
 (e.target as Button).filters[(e.target as Button).filters.length] = new DropShadowFilter(1,45,0x000000,0.4,4,4,2,1,false,true,false);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to do it?

**EDIT:** I'm using the flex Spark theme. The filters array of the button has no elements but changing the filter property removes all applied styles of the Spark theme?

Answer (score 3):

Adboes implementation of this is kinda hacky, it doesn't listen to updates to the array, but only setting the array will update the filters. So this is how you solve it (copying the old array and pushing the new to it).

```
var button:Button = (e.target as Button);
var oldFilters:Array = button.filters;
oldFilters.push(new DropShadowFilter(1,45,0x000000,0.4,4,4,2,1,false,true,false)]);
button.filters = oldFilters;
```

If this doesn't work you will have to create a new array with the contents of the old array, and push your new filter to the new array.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work, only the new filter is applied. I also doesn't understand why you must 'copy' it first to apply the effect. Is this because filters is a dynamic property?

Comment: I think your solution might work. Filters has no elements before apply the new filter. Other styles will be removed, I'm using the flex Spark theme. How can i solve this?

Comment: see my edit. this should work (I've done something like this before).

Comment: Sorry it does work however it removing other styles! The buttons have a background gradient and will be removed after applying the filter (button is transparent with a border). I'm using the Spark Theme, what could be wrong? Even tried to apply the filter with a delay but doesn't help.